# Different behaviour of class python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> class MyKlass:
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> a = MyKlass()
>>> 
>>> type(a)
<type 'instance'>
>>> type(MyKlass)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> 
>>> 
>>> class MyKlass(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> a = MyKlass()
>>> 
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.MyKlass'>
>>> type(MyKlass)
<type 'type'>
>>>
```

In my above code, one class is not inherited from any base class and the other is inherited from `object` base class.

I have read somewhere if you do not inherit explicitly, the default parent class is `object`, am I right?

But if default is `object`, why type to both class is different? When and how these above different behaviour is useful?

Comment: The difference between old style and new style classes exists only in Python 2.x.

Comment: From the first sentence of [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) about "new" style classes (where you inherit from `object`)  and "old" style classes (which doesn't inherit from `object`): "A "New Class" is the recommended way to create a class in modern Python." The word "modern" is meaning Python version 2.2 and up to 2.7, in Python 3 all classes are new-style classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python 3.x, all classes extend `object` implicitly.

But this was not applicable in Python 2.x. Take a look at [New-style and classic classes](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html). In older Python version, you have to explicitly extend the `object` class